# Получить несколько ответов через ajax

Tags: jquery

Есть ajax-скрипт, который отправляет данные к серверу. Этот скрипт возвращает две разные строки, но в одной переменной:

```
.done(function(data){
   console.log(data);
});
```

Как мне отправить одну строку с ключом `data`, а вторую с ключом `response`, например? Одну хочу выводить в консоль в качестве технической информации, а вторую использовать для своих целей и не показывать в консоли.

Например:

```
<?php
//какой-то код
echo json_encode($somedata); // data
//какой-то код
var_dump($another_data);
?>
```

Хочу эти данные выводить с разными ключами и по разному с ними работать.

**UPD:**

Добавил код:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    "technical_data" => $post_data,
    "user_data" => $response
), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Как минимум, не мешало бы нам увидеть, что же всё-таки выводит вызов `console.log`

Comment: @Other добавил код.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте так, что бы сервер вернул JSON, например такой

```
<?php

$somedata = "hello";
$another_data = "world";

$response = array("data" => $somedata, "debug" => $another_data);
echo json_encode($response);
```

В обработчике получите

```
{
    "data":"hello",
    "debug":"world"
}
```

И обращайтесь к нужному вам полю

Comment: Просмотрите, пожалуйста, добавленный код. При попытке обратиться к элементу `data.technical_data` возвращается строка `undefined`.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Как минимум, не мешало бы нам увидеть, что же всё-таки выводит вызов console.log

Comment: Скорее всего там нужен `JSON.parse` после предварительной зачистки лишнего вывода)